# Is there a simple and efficient way to get listed all usb devices in C# or C/C++?

Tags: c#, c++, c, usb, wmi

I have to make a program which monitor usb ports and when an usb device is plugged (joypad, flash drives, mouse, ecc...) I get a unique identifier (a deviceid or something else would be good).
At first I tried with C# using the system.management classes and querying the cim_logicaldevice class each second to get the new device plugged.
Some device returned more rows with DeviceID, but this isn't a problem. The problem is that the memory occupied by the program (in task manager) grows up constantly.
This is the source code:
http://pastebin.com/dQv3cMQC

Is there a way to avoid the growing of the memory usege?
I have to do this program in C++ or C# and it has to be the most efficient possible (because it has to be opened forever).

Comment: just some notes. Note 1: task manager is not very accurate in tracking memory. Note 2: consider enclosing disposable object inside a using(DisposableObject obj = new DisposableObject()){ } instead of calling Dispose directly Note 3: call the GC only for debugging purpose, a full GC collection is done with 3 step GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizer(); GC.Collect();

Comment: using the console to trace the amount of memory used it seems to me the memory is pretty stable

Comment: and if you're aiming for the maximum efficiency (memory wise) don't use c#

Comment: I used using() too, but it seems a problem of the get method of the System.Management searcher.

Comment: I already knew that the task manager was not very accurate, but I think that the memory used growing was real.
I knew also that C# was not the best language for my purpose, so I found libusbx library and I'm making the program in C.

Comment: good C is a better choice for efficiency, anyway just in case you wanna see if there's a real memory growth in c# try and use Debug.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 / 1024); and see if your the memory increase or is stable

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the USBView sample in the WDK. If you are unfamiliar with this, simply run it - this tool walks the entire USB tree on the system and prints out information and descriptor listings for each device.

In your case, I'd start at the RefreshTree() function in this sample, you can then follow the code to see how it enumerates the host controllers, hubs and finally devices. For each device that you find you can look at the bInterfaceClass in the interface descriptors to find out what types of interfaces it is advertising.

The easiest way to get the source to this sample is to install the 7.1.0 WDK which is currently available here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11800